# Prob. 2 (a), Sec. 26 in Munkres' TOPOLOGY, 2nd ed: Is every set compact in the finite-complement topology?

Tags: general-topology

Here's Prob. 2 (a), Sec. 26 in *Topology* by James R. Munkres, 2nd edition:

> Show that in the finite-complement topology on $\mathbb{R}$, every subspace is compact.

I think I can show this.

Now my question is, In this example, is there anything special about $\mathbb{R}$? That is, using the same reasoning, can we not conclude that every set --- finite or infinite --- is compaact under the finite-complement topology?

Comment: There is nothing special about $\Bbb R$; any space with the finite complement topology is hereditarily compact.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, it's always so nice to hear from you!!

Comment: @Brian M. Scott, can we give an example of a topological space (other than the discrete topology) no infinite subspace of which is compact?

Comment: One easy example is any uncountable set with the co-countable topology. To get a simple Hausdorff example, start with an uncountable discrete space and add a point whose nbhds are co-countable.